# How to add Metadata support when enableWebScript is Set?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I'm trying to create wcf service hosted by ASP.NET (I did that some time ago, but now I can't...)

On this step I want to add Meta-data support. Once I've added the following endpoint to configuration:

```
<endpoint address="mex" behaviorConfiguration="McActivationApp.EnrollmentServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
 binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

I've got the following error:

> The endpoint at
>   'http://MyPcName/MCActivation/EnrollmentService.svc/mex'
>   does not have a Binding with the None
>   MessageVersion. 
>   'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'
>   is only intended for use with
>   WebHttpBinding or similar bindings.

I've tried to change 'IMetadataExchange' contract to ''. That cause another error:

> The endpoint at
>   'http://MyPcName/MCActivation/EnrollmentService.svc/mex'
>   does not have a Binding with the None
>   MessageVersion. 
>   'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'
>   is only intended for use with
>   WebHttpBinding or similar bindings.

Please advise, how can I add support for meta data properly?

---

Here is full 'system.serviceModel' section.

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <behaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="McActivationApp.EnrollmentServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
     <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="McActivationApp.EnrollmentServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  <services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="McActivationApp.EnrollmentServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
    name="McActivationApp.EnrollmentService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="McActivationApp.EnrollmentServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
     binding="webHttpBinding" contract="McActivationApp.EnrollmentService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" behaviorConfiguration="McActivationApp.EnrollmentServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
     binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="McActivationApp.EnrollmentService" />
   </service>
  </services>
 </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to resolve an issue: Create new WcfServiceLibrary project and analyzed it's app config.

Based on it I did the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="McActivationApp.EnrollmentServicBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="McActivationApp.EnrollmentService" behaviorConfiguration="McActivationApp.EnrollmentServicBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="McActivationApp.EnrollmentService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="McActivationApp.EnrollmentService" />
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

The MAJOR difference is that I've moved specification of behavior configuration from service endpoints into service itself.

Also I've deleted 'endpoints' behavior and used the only 'service' endpoint

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you remove `behaviorConfiguration="McActivationApp.EnrollmentServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"` from the service tag.  I would also try giving the behaviors unique names, that might lead to some confusion.

Comment: +1 right on - the MEX endpoint **cannot** have any WebScript behavior and stuff like that enabled on it!

Comment: Did you change the contract for the mex endpoint back to "IMetadataExchange"? Make the names for the service and endpoint behaviors unique and update the endpoints?

Comment: No, I read that it is possible (and probably MUST) to use 'own' class to implement metadata exchange contract. It is not clear for me why... but (see my own answer) with other changes it works.